# Show a Kernel and Image of Direct Sum by Block Matrix

Tags: vector-spaces, direct-sum

Prove that a linear transformation P : V → V of a finite dimensional vector
space satisfies $P^2 = P$ if and only if there exists a basis such that the matrix of P with respect to that basis is a block matrix
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        I & 0 \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Hence determine the minimal and characteristic polynomials of P.

I find out if P satisfies $P^2=P$, then V=ker(P) $\oplus$ img(P) But how to use this to get the block matrix and then the characteristic polynomials.

$$\lambda I-P=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        (\lambda-1)I_x & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda I_y  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$det=(\lambda-1)^r\lambda ^y$
How to get the minimal polynomial from it?

Comment: Picl a basis of $\ker P$ and a basis of $\mathrm{Im} P$: the union of these two bases will give you a basis of $V$. In that basis $P$ will appear as that block matrix.

Comment: How to pick the basis to show the block matrix?

Comment: I just told you. the union of ANY basis of $\ker P$ with ANY basis of $\mathrm{Im}\ P$

Comment: How to find the basis since we don't have the exact matrix?

Comment: Well, you simply know it exists, and say it's $v_1 , \dots , v_k$. Any problem with that?

Comment: So the matrix for the image of P can be treated as identity matrix.right?

Answer (score 1):

Take a basis of the image, and a basis of the kernel, and put them together to form a basis of $V$.

Comment: How to take the basis?

Comment: I mean from the information we have

Comment: Can you give me some hint?

Comment: @stedmoaoa Do you know how to find the basis of a kernel of a matrix??

Comment: Yes, but here I don't have the exact matrix of P then how should I find the basis of a kernel?